# What is the preferred way to redirect a request in Pylons without losing form data?

Tags: python, post, request, header, pylons

I'm trying to redirect/forward a Pylons request.  The problem with using redirect_to is that form data gets dropped.  I need to keep the POST form data intact as well as all request headers.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Receiving data from a POST depends on the web browser sending data along.  When the web browser receives a redirect, it does not resend that data along.  One solution would be to URL encode the data you want to keep and use that with a GET.  In the worst case, you could always add the data you want to keep to the session and pass it that way.